# Derivation on p.99 of Salanie, The Economics of Taxation (2nd edition)

Tags: taxation, mechanism-design, optimal-taxation, asymmetric-information

Starting on p. 98 of Salanie's "The Economic of Taxation" (2nd edition), it explains

> To probe it more rigorously, let us define the utility of taxpayer $w$ when he claims to have productivity $w'$:
>   $$
> V(w', w) = u(C(w'), Y(w'), w).
> $$
>   For the mechanism to be revealing, $V$ must be maximal in $w' = w$. Assume that all functions are differentiable and that income $Y$ is positive. Then we have the first-order necessary condition
>   $$
> \frac{\partial V}{\partial w'} (w, w) = 0 \tag{NC1}
> $$
>   and the second-order necessary condition
>   $$
> \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial w'^2}(w,w) \leq 0 \tag{NC2}.
> $$
>   Differentiating (NC1) gives us
>   $$
> \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial w'^2} + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial w' \partial w} = 0
> $$
>   ...

My question is this: How do we arrive at the last equation from (NC1)? If I differentiate 
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial w'} (w', w)
$$
with respect to $w$, don't I just end up with $\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial w'\partial w}$? Likewise, if I differentiate with respect to $w'$, I end up with
$\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial w'^2}$. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is the chain rule. Let $w'(w) = w$, since we are looking for revealing mechanisms. The condition
$$
\frac{\partial V}{\partial w'} (w'(w),w) = 0
$$
holds for all $w$ because the mechanism is revealing for all types. As the (not partial) differentiate w.r.t. $w$ of the right hand side is 0, the same goes for the differentiate of the left hand size, hence
$$
\frac{d \frac{\partial V}{\partial w'} (w'(w),w)}{d w} = 0.
$$
According to the chain rule
$$
\frac{d \frac{\partial V}{\partial w'} (w'(w),w)}{d w} = \frac{d w'(w)}{d w}\cdot \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial^2 w'} (w'(w),w) + \frac{d w}{d w}\cdot \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial w \partial w'} (w'(w),w),
$$
which in a simplified form is
$$
\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial^2 w'} (w'(w),w) + \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial w \partial w'} (w'(w),w).
$$

Answer (score 3):

Why are you doing $\frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial w'^2}$ ?

Even if it is said that $w^{'}=w$ at the optimum, it should be taken different when you differentiate it for first order conditions. So, you differentiate it according to $w^{'}$ and $w$.